# Give focus to a C# UI Application launched from a C++ Shell Extension

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, shell

I have a WPF application launched from a Windows Shell Extension (a simple context menu) that I want to display it focused.

The UI Application appears on focus and active when is launched from a command line, but when I use the windows function ***CreateProcessAsUserW*** and launch it from the context menu is showed without focus. There is some parameter configuration that I am missing when I create the process in the following code?

```
bool launchProcessAsCurrentUser(HANDLE token, const std::wstring& command)
{
    bool result = false;
    void* environment = nullptr;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo{ 0 };

    STARTUPINFOW startupInfo { 0 };
    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);

    const bool impersonateUser = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token);
    if (impersonateUser && CreateEnvironmentBlock(&environment, token, FALSE))
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secA{ 0 };
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secB{ 0 };
        result = CreateProcessAsUserW(token,
                                      0,
                                      const_cast<LPWSTR>(command.c_str()),
                                      &secA,
                                      &secB,
                                      FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
                                      environment,
                                      0,
                                      &startupInfo,
                                      &processInfo);
        DestroyEnvironmentBlock(environment);
    }
    else
    {
        //Log error
    }

    if (impersonateUser)
    {
        RevertToSelf();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** The C# windows is set on focus before it is displayed.

Best Regards,

Comment: Finally, I follow this link https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2014/09/05/reliable-bring-external-process-window-to-foreground-without-c/ and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly setting the show mode by filling in the startup info:

```
// see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
```

Also, since the process you're creating is a window app and not a console app, CREATE_NO_WINDOW seems out of place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've tried this, but still it is not working. The behavior is the same, the UI appears without focus an unactive.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Could it be the app is actually becoming active but some other app becomes active right afterwards? Which application *is* active instead of your new process?

Comment: The scenario is: open the File Explorer, right-click on a file to display the context menu, then click on my menu to open the WPF app. The File Explorer appears focus, but my app dont.